# Creating multiple "views" in a site that slide in when active

Tags: jquery, html, css

MY goal is to have a site with multiple "views", or "panels"—or whatever you want to call them— each taking up the full viewport width-wise, and however much space they need height wise. All the views would be contained in a div, which would slide left or right to "change views" when clicking a button on the fixed header to activate that view. If possible (though not necessary), each view should be scrollable independent of the others, so that when returning to a previously active view, it will be scrolled to the same spot. Though that its not 100% necessary. I picture it all looking something like this:

[image]

of course, the simplest way to do it (which is the way I have it right now) would be to have each panel set to 100% width with a fixed left position (ie, 0%, 100%, 200%, etc), and then animate the left position of each individual panel accordingly, when it's associated button is clicked.

However, I'm trying to simplify it down, so that rather than fixing each panels position, and animating them each, they are instead sitting butted up right next to each other in the larger container, the container being the single element that would slide around.

Right now, each panel is set up with `width:100%; position:relative; display:inline-block;`, but for some reason they are all sitting below each other rather than beside each other. The container is set up with `position:relative;`, and has no set width.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cto6gact/) to demonstrate.

Comment: Are you hiring a freelancer here? buddy, mention the Code that you've tried so far!

Comment: Well, that’s what inline(-block) elements naturally do – they stack up below each other, if there’s not enough space for them to be displayed next to each other. And your container element will only take the width of the viewport, unless you tell it otherwise. So you need to either give that container a large enough width, or use the `white-space` property to prevent your inline-block elements from breaking into multiple rows. The latter of course requires the HTML code to enable that, i.e. no line breaks between the element’s tags.

Comment: @Vikrant Oops. Sorry, it's late here, forgot to link to the fiddle. It's there now.

Comment: @Cbroe Ah, I did not know about a div not automatically stretching past 100% unless explicitly told to do so. Is there a way to force it to do that? I COULD type in a set width for the container, but the number of panels will be variable, and it seems messy to set the width to something like 10000% "just in case".

Comment: It seems that you are looking for something similar to what [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) provides and if its only for the 1st section of your site [check out this](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/oneSection.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ul` `li` structure that I've tried which gives exact same effect that you want to achieve:
Change is you can control them from `<a>` link.

### HTML :

```
<div id="panelContainer" style="position:relative;">
  <a href="#" class="control_next">>></a>
  <a href="#" class="control_prev"><<</a>
<ul>
  <li style=" background-color:red;">SLIDE 1</li>
  <li style=" background-color:green;">SLIDE 2</li>
  <li style=" background-color:blue;">SLIDE 3</li>
</ul>
    <div id="1Panel" class="panel" align="center" style=" background-color:green;"></div>
    <div id="2Panel" class="panel" align="center" style="background-color:red;"></div>
    <div id="3Panel" class="panel" align="center" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
</div>
```

And CSS, JavaScript I've mentioned in [JSFIDDLEm over here](http://jsfiddle.net/cto6gact/1/)